# Printing the page number under arrays of object having the same page number

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I have the following api response data:-

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "number": 1,
      "bookContents": [
        {
          "number": 1,
          "text": "This is is page 1 first content",
          "page": 1
        },
        {
          "number": 2,
          "text": "This is is page 1 second content",
          "page": 1
        },
        {
          "number": 3,
          "text": "This is is page 1 third content",
          "page": 1
        },
        {
          "number": 4,
          "text": "This is is page 2 first content",
          "page": 2
        },
        {
          "number": 5,
          "text": "This is is page 2 second content",
          "page": 2
        },
        {
          "number": 6,
          "text": "This is is page 3 first content",
          "page": 3
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

and the code in component render:-

```
apiResponse.data.bookContents.map((pageContent,key) => <p>{pageContent.text}</p>);
```

The above code just print the text of page contents,I want to segregate the text content according to pageContent.page .

So the output will look like this:-

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the array is already sorted by page number, you can create a variable inside your render function

`let pageNumber = 1`;

And inside your return

```
apiResponse.data.bookContents.map((pageContent, key) => {
    const renderData = [];
    if(pageNumber !== pageContent.page) {
        renderData.push(<><p>{pageNumber}</p><br/></>);
        pageNumber = pageContent.page;
    }
    renderData.push(<p>{pageContent.text}</p>);
    return renderData;
}
```

Comment: Its sorted, but not always starting by number (1) some times the first index comes from api has page number 500 then it continue to next page 501,502 ....

Comment: In that case you can initialise the `pageNumber` by the page number of first object `apiResponse.data.bookContents[0].page`

Comment: let me try and give you feedback

Comment: Did it throw any error? Or wrong data was displayed?

Comment: If i put the variable in render function let pageNumber = 1;, how can i get the first array index page number ?

Comment: Got it, there was an issue with the logic, pageNumber was supposed to be displayed and content.text was supposed to be pushed later, check now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216848/discussion-between-q8root-and-siddharth).

Answer (score 0):

You need a reducer function, which will "reduce" your multiple array elements (that make up 1 page) into 1 array element. Here I used a 2D array, where the first array holds each page and then each nested array holds the content for each page:

```
function mergePages(data) {
    return data.reduce((accumulator, current) => {
        
        // If there is nothing in the accumulator (ie this is the first element of the array),
        // start a new page.
        if (accumulator.length == 0) {
            return [[current]];
        }

        // Get the last page.
        const lastPage = accumulator[accumulator.length - 1];

        // Get the last content.
        const lastContent = lastPage[lastPage.length - 1];

        // If the current page is the same as the last page's content, then we group them together.
        if (lastContent?.page == current.page) {
            return [...accumulator.slice(0, accumulator.length - 1), [...lastPage, current]]

        // Otherwise create a new group.
        } else {
            return [...accumulator, [current]];
        }
    }, [])
}
```

Then you could simply do:

```
mergePages(apiResponse.data.bookContents).map((page, index) => <div>
        {page.map(content => <p>{ content.text }</p>)}
        <p>page number: {page[0].page}</p>
    </div>);
```

Live (non-React) example: https://jsfiddle.net/tpm5vx9k/

Comment: thank you for your effort, it showed the page number under each content.text

Comment: Are you saying that it didn't work? Here's an implementation in regular JS that works on JSfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/tpm5vx9k/